# steps to setting up gtk with code blocks?

Tags: gtk, codeblocks

in windows 7 64bit
i keep getting errors
i have already downloaded the gtk bundle for windows, extracted it and ran some commands
i am trying to go based on this artice
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16468.0
im stuck at step 3 i dont know what bin? from where?
also i dont know how to do 4a, b
thanks for helping

```
-------------- Build: Debug in zxc ---------------

Compiling: main.c
In file included from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AlphaBook\zxc\main.c:2:
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30:21: error: gio/gio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:31,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AlphaBook\zxc\main.c:2:
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkscreen.h:31:19: error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkscreen.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:31,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AlphaBook\zxc\main.c:2:
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:36:18: error: glib.h: No such file or directory
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:37:25: error: pango/pango.h: No such file or directory
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:38:25: error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkscreen.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:31,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AlphaBook\zxc\main.c:2:
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:68: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'typedef'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:78: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'GdkWChar'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:95: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'GdkNativeWindow'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:184: error: expected ')' before 'data'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:190: error: expected ')' before 'data'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:196: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:202: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:210: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:218: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'gint'
In file included from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkevents.h:34,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdisplay.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkscreen.h:33,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:31,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AlphaBook\zxc\main.c:2:
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'G_BEGIN_DECLS'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:71: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'GObject'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:85: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'GObjectClass'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:89: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_colormap_get_type'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:92: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gboolean'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:106: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_colormap_get_system_size'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:112: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:115: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_colormap_alloc_colors'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:121: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_colormap_alloc_color'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:127: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:129: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gulong'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:136: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_parse'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:138: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_hash'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:139: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_equal'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:141: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:143: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_get_type'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:149: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:150: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_white'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:152: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_black'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:154: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_alloc'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:156: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_color_change'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:162: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_colors_alloc'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:169: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gulong'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:170: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gint'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:171: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'gulong'
In file included from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkevents.h:36,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdisplay.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkscreen.h:33,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:31,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AlphaBook\zxc\main.c:2:
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:36: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'G_BEGIN_DECLS'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:76: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'GObject'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:100: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'GObjectClass'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:106: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gdk_drag_context_get_type'
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:108: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:111: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:112: error: expected ')' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:113: error: expected ')' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:114: error: expected ')' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:116: error: expected ')' before '*' token
C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdnd.h:117: error: expected ')' before '*' token
Process terminated with status 1 (1 minutes, 1 seconds)
50 errors, 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my simple explanation for setting up GTK in Code::blocks.

step 1:
 Download gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip (all-in-one bundle) from http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php

step 2. Extract it in c drive or any other place. In my case **C:\GTK** is the directory where I extracted the zip file.

step 3. Now Open Code::Blocks , create new project , from project wizard slect GTK project. Give project name "**GTKsample**" or give name of your choice. Give path **C:\GTK** for GTK location where you extracted the zip file. After creating gtk project yo will see the sample program then build it, build must be successful.

step 4. This is last step, upto step 3 build project must be successful. When you try to run the project you will get message something .dll file (runtime library) missing because we haven't given path for runtime library(.dll file). For this goto the **C:\GTK** directories where you extracted the zip file. Open the **bin** folder only copy all the **.dll**  file and paste it in your project directory **GTKsample\bin\Debug\** with project executable file. In this method every time you create the project you have to keep all the .dll file with project executable file i.e (inside project \bin\Debug\ folder). If you don't want this then copy and paste all the .dll file from bin folder to **C:\windows\system32** directory. 
Now run the project. You must have successfully running project.

You can follow  this **[site](http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com/2013/05/setup-gtk-project-in-codeblocks-windows.html)** for step by step explanation with image of every step.

Comment: when I try to create a gtk+ project and when I specify the gtk folder....it says invalid path.......pls tell me what I am missing....